# Firefox displays <input> box twice if id="DRCTRY" (but not if id is changed)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In the below demo, a form field is displayed conditionally based on what is in another field (when the user types "y" into the question box, the conditional field appears).

Javascript code sets the **display** property to "none" when the conditional field is not wanted.

This works great, except that Firefox renders the first input text box **twice** when the conditional element is first made visible.  The extra "phantom" rendering partially overlaps the other content, but disappears when other input happens.

The really strange thing is that the problem goes away if *I change the id to anything other than "DRCTRY".*  It seems like the identifier "DRCTRY" is somehow special or triggering a bug in Firefox!  This does not happen in Chrome.

My question is: Am I imagining that the specific *id* used causes this problem?   Anyone see anything wrong with my code?

The screen-shot below shows the extraneous rending of the input box.  It was taken immediately after I typed "y" into it.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>

  <form>
    <!-- 
  Firefox 85.0.1 renders the first input box twice when 'y' is typed into it.
  The problem goes away if the id "DRCTRY" is changed to anything else.  
  HOW CAN THIS BE ?!?!
-->
    <label for='DRCTRY'>Show conditional part (y or n)?</label>
    <br />
    <input type='text' id='DRCTRY' name='DRCTRY' value='n' />
    <br />

    <div id='CONDDIV'>
      <p>
        <label for='COND1' id='COND1_label'>Items:</label><br />
        <input type='text' id='COND1' name='COND1' value=''>&nbsp;
      </p>
    </div>

  </form>

  <script>
    changed_func = function() {
      CONDDIV.style.display = DRCTRY.value.match(/^y/i) ? "inline" : "none";
    };
    DRCTRY.oninput = changed_func;
    changed_func(); // process initial value
  </script>

  <p>Next paragraph</p>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is a screen-shot of what I see in Firefox:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's not an extra input element, it's the box for autocomplete. If you don't want to see the box, set `autocomplete="off"` for the input.

Comment: that's [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Comment: This is not the input field being rendered twice - this is the _autocomplete_ feature, that suggests previously entered values for you to choose from now. (And yes, that is usually bound to field names.)

Comment: I don't see the problem in the screenshot, could you please elaborate

Comment: Also I suggest you define variables specifically instead of relying on the browser shadowing the ID as window.ID. So `const condDiv = document.getElementById('CONDDIV'); `

Answer (score 0):

Adding `autocomplete="off"` to the `<input>` element prevents the "problem".

Also, using `document.getElementById("id")` instead of a brower-supplied shadow object avoids trouble if the id is not a valid JavaScript identifier.